# pip installing google-api-python-client to pc - access is denied

Tags: python, google-api

I am getting up and running with google cloud locally. This is a personal PC where I am installing.

I am running, [as suggested](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation), `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`.

I receive the following in response:

```
  Using cached pyasn1-0.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: uritemplate, pyasn1, rsa, httplib2, pyasn1-module
s, oauth2client, google-api-python-client
  Found existing installation: pyasn1 0.1.9
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (pyasn1) has been de
precated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that u
ninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling pyasn1-0.1.9:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215
, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", lin
e 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 778
, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line
 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", li
ne 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line
267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda2\\lib\\site
-packages\\pyasn1-0.1.9-py2.7.egg-info'

C:\Users\%USER%>
```

Has anyone encountered and conquered this issue?

Comment: I have no experience with powershell, but in linux, you need to run the command as the __root__ user ( the administrator)

Comment: @algui91 yep - my mistake for assuming the sole user (aka: me) would be the admin.

Comment: You should mark @jason m answer as correct then.

Comment: @algui91 will do so in 2 days when it is allowed.

Comment: Oh!, I've always forget that restriction xD.

Answer (score 1):

Running powershell as admin solved this problem for me.

If you need assistance running powershell on windows see [this link](http://www.top-password.com/blog/5-ways-to-run-powershell-as-administrator-in-windows-10/).